# Error while testing namespaces in clojure

Tags: testing, clojure

In the test file I require the tested file like this:

```
(ns calc.alg-spec
  (:refer-clojure)
  (:use clojure-test)
  (:require [calc.alg :as alg]))

(deftest silly-test []
  (is (= 2 2)))

(deftest alg-plus-test []
  (is (= (alg/plus 2 2) 4)))

(run-all-tests)
```

The problem is that the first test succeeds while the second throws the following exception:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

What's the problem with the alg namespace and why can't I call its functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code snippet, and the problem lies elsewhere. I would use [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) if you are not already, and follow Leiningen's conventions for testing code.

Comment: thanks for your help, I already use leiningen for testing, I don't know, some functions are tested nicely, others throw this strange exception

Comment: If possible, provide more details about your environment, and the way you run Clojure. The answer has to be there.